# Hoverable on PCs but Clickable on other Devices menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using Twitter Bootstrap for Dropdown Menu, But the problem is that i made the menu hoverable instead of OnClick toggle, Is there a possible way to make this Menu OnClick toggle Collapse like it was before i make it Hoverable, on other touch devices only?

HOVERABLE

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown" href="#">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">4</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">5</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<style>
    .dropdown-menu {}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
</style>
```

In basic bootstrap code, We put `data-toggle="dropdown"` and `id="dropdownMenuButton" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"`

So i was wondering If it is possible to make it Basic again on Touch devices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@media` query and the same break points in the CSS as Bootstrap does, and only apply the `hover` to a non mobile device break points:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */    
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops, Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

This is based on Bootstrap 3 break points.
That will cause the hover to only take affect on screen that are wider than `992px`.

Comment: I really didn't learn anything about this media query before, Am i supposed to type the CSS code for each query if i want multiple style, Can i use these queries to change everything in different widths? And at last Do i have to put these queries in every page?

Comment: It makes a lot of sense to do this as well, as from my understanding hover works a bit differently for mobile devices (browser dependent). On mobile devices the first tap acts as a hover and the second as a selection. Quite often not what you really want.

Comment: The media query essentially allows you to define specific css properties for each pixel width (can be another property as well) interval. Here's a link http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: But it would still a problem, Since the hover would work correctly only on (min-width : 992px), But my code is made for only hoverORclick, And if i changed the code to the basic one, It would break the Hover effect.

Comment: @CaliburVictorious of course you don't need to place there query on every page - place them once in a CSS file, and include the file where you need it. When working with the `@media` you will not have a problem, because on desktop devices when you will hover the dropdown will open "automatically", and on mobile there will be not hover effect, because you don't have CSS that will do it on small devices, so it will be a regular clickable element.